# Multiple targets differing only by variable replacement

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a library that will wind up being semi-publicly released – I am uploading it to Github, but probably won't promote it anywhere – and want to generate documentation (I've gotten kind of fond of Doxygen) so anyone who does wind up wanting to use it knows what to do. Additionally, I find that maintaining the documentation can help me keep track of both program flow and what I still need to write, so I want to document the private and otherwise internal elements as well, not to mention that doing so makes everything more consistent. At the same time, leaving those in the public docs would just wind up cluttering the pages with functions and classes that are worthless outside developing the library itself.

None of that backstory is wholly relevant to my question, though: I'm using cmake to manage my Makefile, and want to create two custom targets, both of which need to replace a variable in a file (in this case, my `Doxyfile.in`) before running their primary command – other than the value of the variable (and, less importantly, the wording of the `COMMENT`) the targets perform the same actions. Due to the fact that I need to set the variable within the target, I'll need to call `configure_file` from within `add_custom_target` if I want to keep it to a single output, but beyond the code duplication, doing so gives me an error:

```
/bin/sh: configure_file: command not found
```

I do have it working using two separate configure calls to two separate files when cmake is first called, but is there a better way to write it, or is using multiple similar lines as I have below actually the best practice? And, yes, I'm sure someone's talked about this somewhere, but none of my searches turned up anything relevant.

```
# Usage from <https://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/tip-of-the-day-cmake-and-doxygen/>
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_INTERNAL_DOCS NO)
    configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Doxyfile.public @ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_INTERNAL_DOCS YES)
    configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Doxyfile.dev @ONLY)

    add_custom_target(doc
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Doxyfile.public
        COMMENT "Generating public API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM
        )
    add_custom_target(doc-dev
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Doxyfile.dev
        COMMENT "Generating internal API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM
        )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

Comment: `is using multiple similar lines as I have below actually the best practice?` - Just wrap steps `configure_file` and creating single doc target into function/macro, and call it twice, with different set of arguments. This is common approach in CMake.

Comment: Thanks! Still new to cmake, so didn't know that was an option.